# Linear partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'd like to know how can I prove this (If it is true, in the worst case the teacher forgot an hypothesis, he always forgets things).

> Show that there doesn't exist $u\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}^2}$ such that $u_x-u_y=-1$ and $u(0,0)=u(1,1)$.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there is a sign error in your PDE. It should be something like $u_x+u_y=-1$. Otherwise you *do* have a solution $u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)$ satisfying the conditions.

This PDE is linear and first order, so you can integrate along characteristics, which is easily seen to be $x=y=t$. Let $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))=(t,t)$. Then

$$ \frac{d}{dt}u(\gamma(t))=\frac{dx}{dt}u_x+\frac{dy}{dt}u_y=-1$$.

Hence $u(\gamma(t))=u(\gamma(0))-t$. In particular, $u(\gamma(1))=u(\gamma(0))-1$, i.e., $u(0,0)=u(1,1)-1$.

Comment: No, I'm saying $u:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as the same as $u\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}^2}$ in any other way, I'll read that slowly and see what can I do from there.

Comment: Right, but that's an unusual way of writing a function from $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. Also please check to see if there is any sign error in the PDE.

Comment: Yes. It's the second time I use it in an Analysis subject and both times It's caused confusion. In other areas it's more common. Thanks for the help, I'll be happy with I've seen until $\gamma(t)$, the rest I'll do it by myself, and read it here afterwards so I can confirm my procedure.

Comment: And there must be a mistake in the sign, but it was given to us like that. My teacher has a very bad memory...